# 3g network connection Problem while using data

Tags: networking, 3g, mobile-network, mobile-data

For last two months or so, the situation in my two years old international HTC One X is that the data is not connecting when it is on 3g network but it is working absolutely fine with 2g network. when its connected to 3g, the mobile network fluctuates, data works with 3g speed for only few minutes and signal drops out. In simple terms, on 3g it fluctuates in data access and network access whereas on 2g it works absolutely fine.

I have changed two 3g enabled sim of different carriers they are also performing the same way in my HTC one x. I have changed the location of the phone, the problem persists. My sim also works fine with another handset in 3g as well as in 2g. So the conclusion is that there is fault with my HTC one x but the question remains what is the fault. Whether software or hardware. I have also done the factory reset but to no avail and I have also switched to custom rom but the problem is still there.

Any solution would be of great help.

Comment: Well researched (+1 for that). Really looks like a fault with either the hardware or the ROM of that specific device. If still under warranty, I'd contact the dealer (to either have the device reflashed or replaced). Did you apply some OTA/ROM upgrade at the time the trouble started? Could be connected then.

Comment: No I didnt apply any OTA/ROM upgrade at the time the trouble started. Its not under warranty and I have also flashed custom ROM myself. The problem is still there.

Comment: Yuck. Pretty strange then, as almost all possibilities have been ruled out with that. Only thing left I can think of then is a new [radio image](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/radio-firmware/info) (if available). If that doesn't help either, guess you've got to live either with unstable 3G, stable 2G, or having to get a new device.

Comment: Is there any chance of hardware issues which is used for network purposes and instead of replacing the device, replacing the hardware could work? Hardware is working very well with 2G and not with 3G, are there separate hardware for both or there is one hardware working for both 2G and 3G.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the hardware question, but AFAIK most of that are integrated multi-purpose circuits, so I doubt it would be an easy task. You can ask a service tech on that, but my guess is a repair would be more (or almost as) expensive than buying a new device.

Answer (score 0):

In your mobile network settings ensure that data in roaming is enabled and working. Secondly, the data channel option will be there in the mobile while addressing the APN and advanced settings. In that option you choose your service provider channel.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the problem has to be with Hardware. On the software side, everything is fine. Might be the hardware of the phone and ROM are not in Sync and thus you are not getting the desired performance for 3G service. Consult official HTC service providers and tell them to address this issue.